# prove a space is epsilon-full of points

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces

I am using a [radial neighbors algorithm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsRegressor.html) to make predictions but am running in to trouble because my dataset does not populate the whole input/query space, in this case a hypercube from [-1,1] along every dimension in $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Essentially I have a bounded space $U$ and a set of points, $X$, and I need to ensure

$$\exists \ x \in X \ s.t. |u-x| \le \epsilon \ \forall \ u \in U$$

In words: I need the space to be fully populated by points, where "full" means that there is no other point in the space more than $\epsilon$ Minkowski distance away from some point in the set.

I am prepared to judiciously add points to $X$ to meet this condition, preferably by creating new points at the centroids of the "[holes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hole.html)", the regions where points from $X$ are all greater than $\epsilon$ distance away. But first I need to detect where these holes are. And then at the end I need to verify my additions have filled the space, iterate the process again if they have not.

#### What I can think to try

A hypersphere of radius $\epsilon$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$ will of course just have a diameter $2\epsilon$. [A hypercube of unit side length in $\mathbb{R}^6$ has a longest length from corner to corner of $\sqrt[p]{6}$](http://www.math.brown.edu/%7Ebanchoff/Beyond3d/chapter2/section05.html), where $p$ is the Minkowski distance parameter. So I can iterate through the space along a grid with points spaced at distance $\frac{2\epsilon}{\sqrt[p]{6}}$ and just fill in holes as I encounter them. But in this scheme I might not be placing new points most effectively, and it might get expensive to do this search, especially if I later end up needing to do it in higher dimension.

I've looked in to [space-filling curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane-FillingFunction.html), but I am not sure how they can help me aside from maybe providing a different order to search my grid.

This question is almost too mathematical for stackoverflow or cross-validated yet too algorithmic for you all.

Comment: Hello and welcome on Math.SE. Please make sure to include your approaches to the problems as it is indicated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Here is an article where they address this problem with rectangles rather than balls https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00683.pdf